# Searching in a .txt file for a specific time

Tags: export, import, text, searching, file-transfer

I've the following code:

```
Import["hoi1.txt"]
```

And it gives me:

> "(time,voltage,current,power)
>   (1,10,5,10*5)
>   (2,20,6,20*6)
>   (3,30,7,30*7)
>   (4,40,8,40*8)
>   (5,50,9,50*9)
>   (6,60,10,60*10)
>   (7,70,11,70*11)
>   (8,80,12,80*12)
>   (9,90,13,90*13)
>   (10,100,14,100*14)
>   (11,110,15,110*15)
>   (12,120,16,120*16)
>   (13,130,17,130*17)
>   (14,140,18,140*18)
>   (15,150,19,150*19)
>   (16,160,20,160*20)
>   (17,170,21,170*21)
>   (18,180,22,180*22)
>   (19,190,23,190*23)"

But I only want the time values $8,9,10$ how can I improve my code so that only those times are printed in my notebook?

Comment: Where did you get `"lines"` idea from?

Comment: @Kuba From http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Text.html but I noticed that I can also drop the "lines" and get the same (see the edit).

Comment: It is `"Lines"`, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be

```
s = Import["hoi1.txt"];
data = ToExpression@StringSplit[
    Rest[
     StringSplit[s, {"(", ") (", ")"}]
     ],
    ","];
Select[data, MemberQ[{8, 9, 10}, #[[1]]] &]
```